# jQuery toggling between 2 items and closing the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 list items and when one is clicked the inner div is toggled open. But the problem is, when both are clicked they both stay open. What I would like it to do is when one is clicked the other will be closed.

**jQuery**

```
$('.register, .signin').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var userclass = $(this).attr('class');
    $('.'+userclass+'-panel').toggle();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="user-status">
    <li><a class="register" href="#">Register</a>
        <div class="register-panel tooltip" style="display: none;">
            <form action="" method="post">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email"><div class="usernamecheck"></div>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password">
                <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" disabled="disabled"><div class="userstatus"></div>
            </form>
        </div><!-- /register -->
    </li>
    <li><a class="signin" href="#">Sign In</a>
        <div class="signin-panel tooltip" style="display: none;">
            <form action="" method="post">
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email"><div class="usernamecheck"></div>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
                <input type="submit" name="signin" value="Sign In"><div class="userstatus"></div>
            </form>
        </div><!-- /register -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `$('.tooltip').not('.'+userclass+'-panel').hide();`
.

```
$('.register, .signin').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var userclass = $(this).attr('class');
    $('.' + userclass + '-panel').toggle();
    $('.tooltip').not('.' + userclass + '-panel').hide();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gb4k7/2/)**

That will hide the form that isn't selected.